# Using telprompt

Tags: tel, telprompt

I need to make a calling functionality from my app. I used tel:// the control doesnt go back to app automatically. If telpromp is used an alert is shown before the call. My first question is will telprompt be rejected in app store? If no then i dont want alert to come. directly call should be made.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you can only find an answer to your first question by submitting your app. As to your second question, an iOS application has to show a prompt asking the user if they want to dial a number. That has to be done one way or another (tel, telprompt). If an app doesn't alert the user, it'll be rejected from AppStore.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I did find a couple people claiming their apps were approved using telprompt:

"I've submited my app that uses telprompt with shared application without the uiwebkit and has been successfully approved by apple.
answered January 19, 2013

Pablo Alejandro Junge"